# Compilation loop error: unknown type name '__kernel_time64_t' in linux headers

Tags: c, linux, header

I have a program which includes these header files:

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
```

I am using `clang` to compile the program, with these added include paths:

```
LINUXINCLUDE =  -I. \
                -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include   \
                -I/usr/include  \
                -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/arch/x86/include  \
                -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/uapi  \
                -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/uapi/linux    \
                -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/uapi/asm-generic  \
                -I/usr/include/linux
```

Then I get this error:

```
> In file included from xdpsock_kern.c:1: In file included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/bpf.h:9: In file
> included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/workqueue.h:9: In file
> included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/timer.h:6:
> In file included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/ktime.h:24: In file
> included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/time.h:6:
> In file included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/seqlock.h:36: In file
> included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/spinlock.h:51: In file
> included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/preempt.h:78: In file
> included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7: In
> file included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/thread_info.h:13: In
> file included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/restart_block.h:10: In
> file included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/time64.h:10: In file
> included from
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/uapi/linux/time.h:6:
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/uapi/linux/time_types.h:8:2:
> error: unknown type name '__kernel_time64_t'
>         __kernel_time64_t       tv_sec;                 /* seconds */
```

I don't know what the right strategy is but for the last 10 errors I already solved I just added the necessary include paths.

Unfortunately I don't know why `time_types.h` expects a type `__kernel_time64_t` although the header itself does not import `posix_types.h` where this type is defined (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.20/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h#L90)

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Note you are looking at posix_types.h for v4.18.20 but you are compiling with v5.3.0, so of course those don't match up.

Comment: Is 5.3.0 the version of Linux you have installed?

Comment: @user253751 Okay, that was my mistake. But it is also available for 5.3: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h - and yes, `5.3.0-28-generic` is the kernel version I have installed